# Select content between header and footer in .rtf

Tags: c#, ms-word, rtf

How do I get only the content of the .rtf file?
How do I find where .rtf file's header stops and footer starts in C#?

I've read it with

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(myRtfFilePath))
{
    fullText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
}
```

and I can find the content I write like this

```
var startIndex = fullText.IndexOf("start");
```

but that means I have to manually add 'start' and 'end' to my .rtf file so that I can see where content starts and where it ends.

Answer (score -1):

To extract just the content of an RTF file in C#, you can use the **System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox** control, which has a built-in capability to handle RTF format. Here's an example of how you might do this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class RtfExtractor
{
    public string ExtractRtfContent(string rtfFilePath)
    {
        string content = "";

        // Create a RichTextBox control
        using (RichTextBox richTextBox = new RichTextBox())
        {
            // Load the RTF file into the RichTextBox
            richTextBox.LoadFile(rtfFilePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

            // Extract the plain text content
            content = richTextBox.Text;
        }

        return content;
    }
}
```

Regarding your second question about finding where the RTF file's header stops and the footer starts.

If you've manually added markers like "start" and "end" in your RTF file, you can find the content between these markers using IndexOf as you've mentioned. Here's an example:

```
class RtfMarkerFinder
{
    public string ExtractContentBetweenMarkers(string rtfFilePath, string startMarker, string endMarker)
    {
        string fullText = "";

        // Read the entire RTF file into a string
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(rtfFilePath))
        {
            fullText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Find the index of the start marker
        int startIndex = fullText.IndexOf(startMarker);
        if (startIndex == -1)
        {
            // Start marker not found
            return "";
        }

        // Find the index of the end marker after the start marker
        int endIndex = fullText.IndexOf(endMarker, startIndex + startMarker.Length);
        if (endIndex == -1)
        {
            // End marker not found after the start marker
            return "";
        }

        // Extract the content between the markers
        int contentStart = startIndex + startMarker.Length;
        int contentLength = endIndex - contentStart;
        string extractedContent = fullText.Substring(contentStart, contentLength);

        return extractedContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nitesh. Thank you for trying but there are several things wrong with the answer that's obviously generated by AI. I know, I tried AI, got the same code, didn't work. Richtextbox doesn't work because format of it is not the same as Microsoft Word's format for .rtf files. It doesn't include header, footer or images. And for the second part I asked if it can be done without start/end tags, and even then the code won't work because these tags are saved between curly brackets which "you" didn't account for. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).